# get nan error for the result of the normalization function in c++

Tags: c++

i would like to use the glm::normalize() in C++ to normalize a glm::vec3 vector, but the result of the normalization is nan, can you please help me to resolve it? Thank you!

this is my code below:

```
glm::vec3 a(4.58463e-41,-9.83211e-09,-2.4355e+26);
glm::vec3 n = glm::normalize(a);
cout<<n.x<<n.y<<n.z<<endl;
```

the result of the print is :

```
clang++  -Ofast -funsafe-math-optimizations -march=native -o build/RedNoise build/RedNoise.o  build/CanvasPoint.o  build/CanvasTriangle.o  build/Colour.o  build/DrawingWindow.o  build/ModelTriangle.o  build/RayTriangleIntersection.o  build/TextureMap.o  build/TexturePoint.o  build/Utils.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
./build/RedNoise
nannannan
^CExiting
```

Comment: The magnitude of the number you pass in for `z` is mind-boggling. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: `glm::vec3` stores its components as `float`.  You have [exceeded the limit of what a `float` can store](https://godbolt.org/z/o651h8E55).

Comment: That vector looks like the result of either a faulty calculation or a lack of initialization.

Comment: i am working on computer graphics, i need to deal with the normal vector of the image, it seems like that my vector is not very reasonable hhhh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need (I doubt you do) to normalize such crazy long vectors, you should make sure their length is reasonable to start with. glm is limited to float (at least for this API).

```
double x = 4.58463e-41;
double y = -9.83211e-09;
double z = -2.4355e+26;

// reduce to reasonable range while keeping the normalized value the same
while (x > 1e+8 || y > 1e+8 || z > 1e+8 ||
       x < -1e+8 || y < -1e+8 || z < -1e+8)
{
    x /= 2.0;
    y /= 2.0;
    z /= 2.0;
}

glm::vec3 a(x, y, z);
glm::vec3 n = glm::normalize(a);
cout<<n.x<<n.y<<n.z<<endl;
```